# C# preprocessor macro to add code on build?

Tags: c#, macros, preprocessor, vscode-tasks

I am writing code in VSCode.
I have a .sql file with a query I want to add all the text from the .sql into my c# file, but I want to do it automaticly just before the code is built.

Is this something I can do with a Preprocessor macro, or maybe a VSCode task?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you considered using [string resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps) to store the SQL instead?

Comment: Or you can add the file as "embedded resource"